# Set starting point for cycle()

Tags: ruby

Given this array: `a = ["a", "b", "c"]`

If I run `a.cycle { |x| puts x }` I get `print, a, b, c, a, b, c,.. forever.`

Is there a way to set the starting point so that it would begin with "b" or the second index like this: `print, b, c, a, b, c, a,.. forever.` ?

Comment: Mi mi mi. This is another usecase. Thank you _very_ much regardless! I will however stick to waiting a few days before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array#rotate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate)

`a.rotate.cycle {|x| puts x}`

Pass an argument to `rotate` to shift to whichever index you want.