# How to get the next element in an array but get first if current is last

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I have an array of color codes:

```
array = %w(#646C74 #F68848 #1FA45C etc...)
```

Every time I query the array I compare with what color was lastly used and want to get the next one. If the last one used is the last in the array, I want the first one.

Is there a more dedicated or succinct way to solve this than:

```
index_of_last_used_color = array.index(last_used_color)
next_position = index_of_last_used_color + 1
if color = array[next_position]
    return color
else
    return array.first
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, there is plain old good arithmetics (modulo calc) still alive:

```
array = %w(#646C74 #F68848 #1FA45C)
index = 1234
item = array[index % array.size]
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. But I don't understand your example index position of `1234` ?

Comment: @FellowStranger It's just a random number to make you understand that with modulo operator you always end in the array range

Comment: It also works as expected with negative indices, i.e. `-1 % array.size` gives you the last item's index, `-2 % array.size` the second to last and so on.

Answer (score 10):

Use `cycle` method, an enumerator seems what you're looking for.

```
color_cycle = %w(#646C74 #F68848 #1FA45C).cycle
color_cycle.next # => "#646C74"
color_cycle.next # => "#F68848"
color_cycle.next # => "#1FA45C"
color_cycle.next # => "#646C74"
color_cycle.next # => "#F68848"
```

Comment: You should use another variable name, though: `array` is no longer an array ;-)

Comment: Does it work `colors_enum` for you? Naming is an hard problem for me :D

Comment: Sure, `color_cycle` would be fine, too.

Comment: Looking at the docs for `cycle` I don't seem to find the possibility to give the `enumerator` a starting point. I.e. is it possible to get next element without starting from first element each time?

Comment: @FellowStranger you call `cycle` once and store the result. Then, you keep calling `next` to get one value after another.

Comment: OK thanks. So not possible to get "next" value just by pointing to any position.

Comment: @FellowStranger the whole point of `cycle` is that you don't have to remember the position. `cycle` does that for you.

Comment: @FellowStranger I think it's not possible but you might rotate the array before call cycle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597835/set-starting-point-for-cycle/26597884

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the docs for cycle I don't seem to find the possibility to give the enumerator a starting point. I.e. is it possible to get next element without starting from first element each time?

I'd do something like this:

```
colors = array = %w(646C74 F68848 1FA45C)
```

"randomly" grab a color from the list:

```
first_color = colors.delete_at(rand(colors.size))
colors # => ["646C74", "1FA45C"]
```

and push it onto the end of the list:

```
colors << first_color
```

Then you can start cycling after you used the first color:

```
color_wheel = colors.cycle
colors.size.times do
  puts color_wheel.next
end

# >> 646C74
# >> 1FA45C
# >> F68848
```